# Can I reuse the key from ng-repeat in a model?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to reuse the *key* from the ng-repeat for the model of the input field *ng-model="...key.percent"*.

Something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, val) in $ctrl.offer.properties">
  <fieldset ng-if="val">
    <h3>{{$ctrl.getLabelFor(key)}}</h3>
    <md-input-container>
      <input name="procent" ng-model="$ctrl.offer.properties.key.procent"/>
    </md-input-container>
```

I want to keep my *properties* as they are.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: if you want key to be your model then you can do just `<input type="text" ng-model="key.procent" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can access it via key by wrapping key inside `[]` like below.

```
ng-model="$ctrl.offer.properties[key]procent"
```